# Can we make namespace prefixes in xml mapping dynamic?

Tags: xml, dataweave

I have a one to one mapping of two xsd which are totally same. In sample for namespaces sometimes the prefix is ns1 and sometimes it is com . I was wondering if I can do something so that it takes whatever prefix comes.

Comment: prefixes only have a meaning within a *single* chunk of XML. `<a:thing xmlns:a="uri:thingy">` and `<b:thing xmlns:b="uri:thingy">` are *exactly the same thing*. It's not a problem if both occur inside the same XML either.

Comment: What is "it"? What are you actually doing? Generally, software that processes XML should accept any prefix, it should only care about the namespace (but the "should" doesn't mean that all software follows this good practice.)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the namespace prefix dynamic by including it between parenthesis:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var z="x"
---
a @((z):'123') : {
    b: 'b'
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<a x="123">
  <b>b</b>
</a>
```

Although I'm not sure if it is a good idea to do it.